# bootpag pagination triggering multiple ajax calls

Tags: jquery

I am using the following code to generate a new table (via ajax) each time the user clicks on my pagination

```
$('#paginationajax').bootpag({
  total: y/4
}).on("page", function(event, num){
  $(".table__lines").empty();
  loyaltyActivity.init(num, frmdate, todate); //ajax call
  alert(num);
  return false;
});
```

`y` = the total number of rows - divided by 4 because I want 4 rows at a time

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong? FYI I am using bootpag 1.05

Answer (score 1):

I know it can be a little bit later, but if your problem is regarding bootpag triggering multiple ajax calls, there is a bug with this plug-in. To workaround this issue, you can bind a new 'click' method instead use the .on bind.

It seems like this:

```
$('#paginationajax').bootpag({
    total: y/4
});

$('ul.pagination.bootpag li').click(function() {
    var num = $(this).attr('data-lp');
    loyaltyActivity.init(num, frmdate, todate); //ajax call
    alert(num);
    return false;                                
});
```